# Printing or downloading after a form

Tags: google-apps-script

The premise is a have a fault reporting system for my company which functions by myself entering information into a form, which then has a GAS script which takes the values from the form, puts them into a template document, and then emails the document to me.

I want the document to print as well. 
Now as far as I can see there is no GAS implementation of Google Cloud Print, so the only other option seems to be serving the PDF as a download.

How do I go about offering the PDF as a download (or opening it in the browser) after the form is filled out.

A bit more info:
This is all using Google Drive, with Google Forms for the input and Google Docs for the template. The code is implemented through an onSubmit trigger.
Pastebin of my current email code: http://pastebin.com/LspdSgpu

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What have you tried so far?  If we can see where you are, we can offer suggestions to help you along.

Comment: I have the form submitting, the template takes the values fine, and it PDFs the entire thing and sends it to my email. It also saves the values in a spreadsheet on Google Drive. However, past this point my knowledge of GAS kind of falters. 

I have tried implementing some kind of download system, however my knowledge on GAS scripting falls a bit short.

Comment: Instead of writing that down here, include it in the question.  There's a handy dandy edit button right below the question specifically for situations like this one.  If you also include the code for the download system you tried to implement, that would help us help you.

Comment: When you edit this question as @Enigmadan suggests, you should also be more specific about what type of Form you are using. (GoogleDocs Forms service, a form based on UiService or HtmlService, or something completely different?) That will determine what you can do after form submission - each service has its own capabilities.

Comment: Thanks, added some extra info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing/Downloading from Google Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305120/printing-downloading-from-google-forms)